# How to add CSS to Wordpress

Tags: css

I am struggling to get custom CSS to work in Wordpress.  I am using version 6.1.1.

I want to turn off underlining of the link in the site title when you hover over it.  I am using a Twenty-twenty three theme.  I have attempted this by setting a custom class on the site title block (site_banner), and then added the following CSS to style.css:

```
.site_banner a:hover {
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

Either this stylesheet is not being included, or it is being overridden somewhere.  I'm not sure how/where I am supposed to put my code, or how to debug the problem.  I can't find anything about custom CSS in the Wordpress documentation, other than altering site global themes.  A few tutorials I have found have told me that what I am doing should work.  And it has in previous versions of Wordpress.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are some helpful threads on wordpress.org:

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/hovering-settings/

https://wordpress.org/support/theme/twentytwentythree/

You can use the hidden customizer option to add your CSS. Append customize.php to your site admin URL.
E.g. https://example.com/wp-admin/customize.php

And add your custom CSS in the Additional CSS section and this should do the trick.
[image]

Comment: Any idea why the new version of WP hides this?  Is WP moving away from allowing you to fine-tune a site's appearance?

Comment: Oh and yeah, it worked perfectly using the Additional CSS.  Thanks!

Comment: @esotechnica " Is WP moving away from allowing you to fine-tune a site's appearance?" Nope, Customizer availability  depends on theme. For ref: https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/customizer/

I personally feel Additional CSS option should still be available even if the theme supports Full site editing, it's helpful for small css improvements.